# usestate to move component on page to a different area when clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have some code:

```
//Top row holding one card
const Top = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className='row'>
         <Card />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default top;


//Bottom row of cards
const Heroes = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
        <p>Select a hero</p>
        <div className="row">
            <Card cardSize={'little-card'} hero={'Spiderman'}/>
            <Card cardSize={'little-card'} hero={'Batman'}/>
            <Card cardSize={'little-card'} hero={'Superman'}/>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Heroes;
```

Each card component contains a superhero. The hero prop sets the image and also serves as an identifier. There is an empty space above.
[image]

When you click one, it should move from its place to the container above, like so:
[image]
Then it when clicked again while at the top, it should move back to its original place:
[image]
Can someone dumb this down for me or show me how to do this? Code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: actually , how do you use the Top component ?

Comment: @YassineCHABLI I only put it there for demonstration purpose, I do not use it in my code

Answer (score 0):

You can add `useState` for checking which card gets selected, and then pass that state handling `selectCard` to `Card` component

```
const Heroes = (props) => {
  const [selectedCard, setSelectedCard] = useState()
  const selectCard = (heroName) => { setSelectedCard(heroName) }
  return (
    <div>
        <p>Selected hero: {selectedCard}</p>
        <p>Select a hero</p>
        <div className="row">
            <Card cardSize={'little-card'} hero={'Spiderman'} selectCard={selectCard}/>
            <Card cardSize={'little-card'} hero={'Batman'} selectCard={selectCard}/>
            <Card cardSize={'little-card'} hero={'Superman'} selectCard={selectCard}/>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Heroes;
```

After that, modifying your `Card` component like below

```
const Card = (props) => {
   return <div onClick={() => { props.selectCard(props.hero) }}>{props.hero}</div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, what is heroName in this context? Can you explain

Comment: `heroName` will be Spiderman, Batman, etc. from `hero` prop. By the way, I modified `Card` component for a better understanding @Wendigo